# Laravel forms won't work on Android 6

Tags: php, android, forms, laravel, eloquent

I have a web page written in laravel 5.2 framework,bootstrap and my intention is to use this as mobile web page, for now the page works fine on the desktop devices laptop  or any IOS(apple device ).The problem is that when I try to access the page through an android device I can only view fill the form but cannot  upload a picture as the guards for validation throw an error that the picture was not uploaded.In other words my validation thinks I have not uploaded any image but I have so here is the code and also have provided a link to the actual page where you can see the page in question any help appreciated [link](http://development.dmnlogistics.co.uk/testform) and the code behind it

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit'])) 
        {
                $check = getimagesize($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name']);
                if($check !== false) 
                {

                    $uploadOk = 1;
                    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) 
                        {


                            $spotCheckImage = new SpotCheckImagePath();
                                    $spotCheckImage->imgname =  $new_file_name;
                                    $spotCheckImage->imagepath = $target_file;
                                    $spotCheckImage->spotCheckComment()->associate($spotCheckComment);
                                    $spotCheckImage->save();

                            Session::flash('success', 'The file '. basename( $_FILES['pic']['name']). 'has been uploaded.'); 
                            return Redirect::to('testform');

                        } else 
                            {

                                 Session::flash('error',  'Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.');
                                 return Redirect::to('testform');

                            }
                } 
                else 
                {

                    $uploadOk = 0;
                    Session::flash('error',  'File is not an image.');
                    return Redirect::to('testform');
                }
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Tim any errors or any more information, what browser on android?

Comment: @luceos no errors nothing happens it just won't upload try the link and see

Comment: @Macro Man- reworded the question for your better understanding please visit the link if you have an android device and try to upload the picture to see what will happen.The problem once again is the fact that i can not upload a picture from an android device but can from any other device

Comment: @luceos- reworded the question for your better understanding please visit the link if you have an android device and try to upload the picture to see what will happen.The problem once again is the fact that i can not upload a picture from an android device but can from any other device